# Parsing XML DOM in VBA Excel - Parents and Children

Tags: xml, vba, excel, dom

I would like to extract from this xml file a list of "serialnum" for all tracks, along with the "category" of each serialnum's parent compactdisc. I.e.

```
00001   Type A
00002   Type A
...
00007   Type B
00008   Type B
```

I figured out how to extract a list of serial nums, but how do I extract the associated category from a few levels "up" the XML chain? I am comfortable re-sizing the array, but I left it at length 100 for simplicity. I am also comfortable with multidimensional arrays, so perhaps I could write a 2D array containing "Serialnum" in the first column and "Category" in the second column? I'm comfortable writing a loop (or loop in a loop) to iterate through that scenario, but how do I *call* for the "category" value per each Serialnum? Thank you.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<compactdiscs>
  <compactdisc category="Type A">
    <artist type="individual">Frank Sinatra</artist>
    <title numberoftracks="4">In The Wee Small Hours</title>
   <tracks>
      <track serialnum="00001">In The Wee Small Hours</track>
      <track serialnum="00002">Mood Indigo</track>
      <track serialnum="00003">Glad To Be Unhappy</track>
      <track serialnum="00004">I Get Along Without You Very Well</track>
   </tracks>
    <price>$12.99</price>
  </compactdisc>
  <compactdisc category="Type B">
    <artist type="band">The Offspring</artist>
    <title numberoftracks="5">Americana</title>
   <tracks>
      <track serialnum="00005">Welcome</track>
      <track serialnum="00006">Have You Ever</track>
      <track serialnum="00007">Staring At The Sun</track>
      <track serialnum="00008">Pretty Fly (For A White Guy)</track>
   </tracks>
    <price>$12.99</price>
  </compactdisc>
</compactdiscs>
```

VBA (Excel). This code just extracts a list of Serialnum's, without "Category" data, but I want to add "Category" data.

```
Sub CDload()
'Create new sheet for ouput
'Set x = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

'define the object and load the first XML sheet
Set Target_XML_File = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Target_XML_File.Load (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\CDs.xml")
Set CurrentNode = Target_XML_File.SelectNodes("/compactdiscs/compactdisc/tracks/track/@serialnum")

Dim arrayx() As String
ReDim arrayx(100, 0)

For i = 0 To (CurrentNode.Length - 1)
    arrayx(i, 0) = CurrentNode(i).NodeValue
Next i

'write array to worksheet, starting on row 2
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(101, 1)) = arrayx

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. The solution is to use the .ParentNode syntax combined with the .getAttribute("XXXXXX") syntax. Note that I also changed the "select node" syntax so that instead of selecting the attribute initially, I select the element and then use the "getattribute("XXXXXX") syntax. See working code below.

```
Sub CDload()

'define the object and load the first XML sheet
Set Target_XML_File = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Target_XML_File.async = False
Target_XML_File.Load (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\CDs.xml")
Set CurrentNode = Target_XML_File.SelectNodes("/compactdiscs/compactdisc/tracks/track")

Dim arrayx() As String
ReDim arrayx(100, 0)
Dim arrayx2() As String
ReDim arrayx2(100, 0)

For i = 0 To (CurrentNode.Length - 1)
    arrayx(i, 0) = CurrentNode(i).getAttribute("serialnum")
    arrayx2(i, 0) = CurrentNode(i).ParentNode.ParentNode.getAttribute("category")
Next i


'write array to worksheet, starting on row 2
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(101, 1)) = arrayx
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2), ActiveSheet.Cells(101, 2)) = arrayx2

End Sub
```